# Two MongoDB containers same port - how to access each of them from host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to setup 2 containers using compose for MongoDB. Each container should have different IP but the same default port.

Is it possible to access each of them from the host machine (same exposed port, different IP)?

Comment: In general you can't access the container-private IP addresses from outside Docker.  If your host has multiple network interfaces (possibly virtual ones) you could use Compose `ports:` to bind each MongoDB instance to a different host interface.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you share some tips how to use diffeent virtual host interface?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that really isn't an issue. All you need to do is mention the IP in the connection string.

First Container:

```
mongodb://username:password@host1:port/
```

Second Container:

```
mongodb://username:password@host2:port/
```

I am not exactly sure if this was your question. If you were trying to ask if you can run multiple containers from a single docker file (judging by the tags) then yes, you can look into Kubernetes.

Comment: I know this, the problem is that i want to work with 2 mongodb containers on the same single host. Thanks for your time.